# Help with Ghidra and rewriting assembly

Tags: assembly, ghidra

I'm learning reversing and for that I use Ghidra.
There is program I'm trying to modify so I can recompile it and make it work.
I have a code that ghidra decompile like this: `data=function(4)`
Going inside the function I think to make it work I need to pass a zero.
In the assembly I can read:

```
PUSH RBP
MOV RBP,RSP
MOV EDI,0x4
CALL function
MOV qword ptr [data],RAX
```

What I understand from that (and I'm propably wrong)
is that  the `MOV EDI,0x4` is the 4 given in the function so I tried to rewrite it in Ghidra with `0x0` and it replace the:

```
bf 04 00 00 00 with bf 00 00 00 00
```

I thought it would be enough and I exported as an ELF but when I start the program I get a segmentation fault so I guess I'm doing something wrong with the memory.

```
    (gdb) x/10xi $rip
=> 0x555555401888:      mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x55555540188b:      test   %rax,%rax
   0x55555540188e:      jne    0x55555540189a
   0x555555401890:      mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x555555401895:      jmp    0x55555540199d
   0x55555540189a:      movq   $0x0,-0x50(%rbp)
   0x5555554018a2:      mov    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x5555554018a6:      mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x5555554018a9:      call   0x5555554008f0 <strlen@plt>
   0x5555554018ae:      mov    %rax,-0x48(%rbp)
```

I would like some help to understand what I'm doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: Can you diff the two ELF files - before and after editing and post a diff here too?
Also can you attach the ELF with gdb and post the crashing instruction?

Comment: (gdb) run Results : Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555401888 in ?? ()

Comment: command : diff <(objdump -d elffile) <(objdump -d elffileWithZero ) Result : 2c2 < elffile: format de fichier elf64-x86-64 --- > elffileWithZero: format de fichier elf64-x86-64 222c222 < b50: bf 04 00 00 00 mov $0x4,%edi --- > b50: bf 00 00 00 00 mov $0x0,%edi –

Comment: Also can you disassemble the bytes where the application crash? Or just attach the original ELF file?

Comment: Bytes view in ghidra 
c3 55 48 89 e5 bf 00 00 00 00 e8 19 0b 00 00 48 89 05 b7 24 20 00 48 8d 3d 82 ff ff ff

Comment: The crashing instruction is C3 ret ?

Comment: you quite lost me there i think the bytes view i sent is the start of the function and the first line where the result of the function where 4 is passed is stored in a data.
Here is a link to the edited elf https://gitlab.com/CarcajouFurieux/elffile
it is related to a ctf which i why i was reluctant to just send the file and i'm not asking for the answer of the ctf. I just want to know what i'm doing wrong since i'm starting to learn reverseing

Comment: Disassemble the crashing instruction and the surrounding lines to see if you trigger an invalid memory read/write/ `x/10xi $rip` after the crash in gdb. Please add details in the original post.

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: This back and forth is gonna take a while. Otherwise a few points
1. See where the application crashed, what was the expected address it is trying to read.
2. Attach gdb to the original elf file and see what is being read at that instruction and what changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the consequences of patching an instruction. What gets changed by the instruction - both data and control flow.
Based on the comments I think you are trying to patch this part

```
.text:0000000000000B4C                 push    rbp
.text:0000000000000B4D                 mov     rbp, rsp
.text:0000000000000B50                 mov     edi, 4
.text:0000000000000B55                 call    sub_1673
```

to

```
.text:0000000000000B4C                 push    rbp
.text:0000000000000B4D                 mov     rbp, rsp
.text:0000000000000B50                 mov     edi, 0
.text:0000000000000B55                 call    sub_1673
```

Based on this you can see what will change when `sub_1673` gets executed.

```
...
.text:000000000000167C                 mov     [rbp+nmemb], rdi
.text:0000000000001680                 cmp     [rbp+nmemb], 0
.text:0000000000001685                 jnz     short loc_1691
.text:0000000000001687                 mov     eax, 0
.text:000000000000168C                 jmp     loc_1736
...
.text:0000000000001736                 add     rsp, 28h
.text:000000000000173A                 pop     rbx
.text:000000000000173B                 pop     rbp
.text:000000000000173C                 retn
```

Based on the calling convention 0 will be copied to `rdi`. It is then compared to 0 and then a jump is taken if its non zero. If its zero the function returns with a return value of zero. Something like

```
int sub_1673(size_t a1) {
    if(!a1) return 0;
    ....
}
```

If the value was non-zero some memory is allocated and the pointer is saved to some global variable. In your case - after the patch the variable stays 0 and the application crashes while read NULL(0) address.

Comment: thanks it clarified what is happening and what do to